# How to calculate the number of variables and constraints in the dual of a linear program?

Tags: linear-programming, duality-theorems

How can I calculate the number of total variables and constraints (without counting variable domain constraints)? Required to derive the dual model. LP relaxation of a linear assignment problem is being considered and two groups of 63 elements are given.

Comment: What do you mean, calculate the number? If you have an LP in front of you, can't you just count the variables and constraints?

Answer (score 0):

In the dual problem, there is a variable for each primal constraint and a constraint for each primal variable.